# Decimal allowance in money format

Tags: html

I am using the below scripts. I have gotten it to use the two digit money when doing the math but it wont let me submit the form using change.

```
<script>
function total_amount(){
    var table = document.getElementById('line_item');
    for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
        qty = table.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
        unit = table.rows[i].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
        var total = (qty * unit).toFixed(2); // format the result to 2 decimal places
        table.rows[i].cells[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = total;
    }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control qty1');
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(arr[i].value)) tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot.toFixed(2);
}
    </script>
```

When you try to include change (ex. 1504.33) the form then tells you to use a whole number only.

Comment: I don't see any form here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for an input tag the default step is 1.  Change it to .01 and you'll be fine

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" step=".01">
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: please accept answer.  Thanks